# How to display "Working" toast from Google Docs add-on

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

When starting Spreadsheet or Doc add-ons I've obtained from the add-on stores, I see an animated progress toast at the bottom of the window:

[image: toasty goodness]

That doesn't show up for my own add-ons, so I'm guessing that it's not placed by the add-on framework, but is something under the control of the add-on itself. The [Preview Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) doesn't mention it, it's not in the [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs), nor does it appear in the [UI Style guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style). Then again, there's no elements in the [CSS](https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css) that would apply, either.

How can my add-on trigger this toast during initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That progress indicator actually is placed by the add-on framework, for true add-ons. (As opposed to contained scripts using the add-on menus.)

It is not under control of your script.

Comment: You won't believe me but I was just wondering this morning "where do these special spinners come from ?" Now I know ! thx & +1 - auxilary question : one should remove any other spinner we place in the sidebar then ?

Comment: No, keep your own spinner, as the "Working" toast is only presented for the time it takes to hand control over to the add-on.